Reference request for realizing a simplicial set as the homotopy colimit of its simplices

I know that
$$X\simeq hocolim_{Simp(X)}\Delta^n,$$
where $Simp(X)$ is the category of simplices of $X$, I know this for example because of proposition 7.5 of the nLab's page for homotopy limits. Though I have seen it appear here and there in various proofs. 
However I cannot seem to find a textbook source for this, which I would like just because it feels better to cite a text book than the nLab. According to exercise 3.7 of this exercise sheet, this result can be found in Hirschhorn's book on model categories, but didn't find it there. I did my best to search in Riehl's book on abstract homotopy theory and in the book about simplicial homotopy theory in Jardine and Goerss. But was unsuccessful. 
I am not saying this result cannot necessarily be found there, just after and hour of scrolling through those three pdf, and not really knowing where else to look, I taught I might turn to you guys. 
Any help is much appreciated, thank you so much.

In Hirschhorn, this is Proposition 15.10.4(1) and Theorem 15.10.8(2). To see this, recall that one can compute the homotopy colimit of a functor $F\colon I\to\mathcal{M}$, where $I$ is a Reedy category and $\mathcal{M}$ is a model category, by computing a Reedy cofibrant replacement of $F$ and then applying the usual colimit functor to this replacement. Hence if we know that the diagram $\mathrm{Simp}(X)\to\mathrm{sSet}, (\sigma\in X_n)\mapsto \Delta^n$ is Reedy cofibrant, then the above two statements give you that $\mathrm{hocolim}_{\mathrm{Simp}(X)}\,\Delta^\bullet$ is already given up to weak equivalence by $\mathrm{colim}_{\mathrm{Simp}(X)}\,\Delta^\bullet\cong X$. Finally, to see that $\mathrm{Simp}(X)\to\mathrm{sSet}, (\sigma\in X_n)\mapsto \Delta^n$ is Reedy cofibrant (Definition 15.3.3(2)), we compute the latching map at a simplex $\sigma\in X_n$, which is the boundary inclusion $\partial\Delta^n\hookrightarrow\Delta^n$ and therefore a cofibration in $\mathrm{sSet}$.
